# React Components work when I rename them but after refreshing the page the components stop working

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I am using tw-elements,tailwind css with vite and I have created a component called "Carouselhead". It was working fine until I restarted my dev server. It shows white empty image, there's no error in the console.
However when I try to drag the image I can see it was imported but isn't rendered on the page.
If I slightly change the name of the compontent like "Carouselheax" it works but if I hit refresh it goes blank again.
Exactly same thing is happening with another component.

My vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(
    {include: "**/*.jsx",}
  )],
  
})
```

Before Changing the component name

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDwG2.jpg)

After slightly changing the component name from Carouselhead to Carouselheax it starts working

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVoTr.jpg)

After I hit refresh the whole page goes blank because there's no export name 'Carouselheax'

Renaming the component again gives blank image again.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/yashsingh-0/pathpuja

I have checked the import name cases, they are correrct. I've tried disabling the HMR its not working. I think the problem is with HMR because if I try renaming a component to something which doesn't exist, It doesn't throw an error until I manually refresh.

Comment: By "component name" do you mean the file name or the exported *React* class/function component? Can you also clarify what you by a "Vite component"? AFAIK there's no such thing.

Comment: I meant the function component. And sorry for writing "vite component" I meant react. 
I have created a file called Carouselhead,jsx and in that file I have created a react component called Carouselhead.